# why object is not being initializeed Globally in Java?

Tags: java, oop, object

I am trying to do simple encapsulation program. The source has given below.

```
package encap;
public class Encap
  {

    public static void main(String[] args)
      {
           NewClass1 call = new NewClass1(3);
           call.PrintNumber();
      }

  }



package encap;
public class NewClass1
  {
    private int numberNewClass1;

    NewClass call = new NewClass(getNumberNewClass1());
    public NewClass1(int number)
      {
          setNumberNewClass1(number);
      }  

    public void PrintNumber()
      {
//          NewClass call = new NewClass(getNumberNewClass1());

          System.out.println("NewClass1");
          System.out.println(getNumberNewClass1());

          System.out.println("NewClass");
          System.out.println(call.getNumber());
      }

    public int getNumberNewClass1()
      {
        return numberNewClass1;
      }
    public void setNumberNewClass1(int numberNewClass1)
      {
        this.numberNewClass1 = numberNewClass1;
      }
  }

package encap;
public class NewClass
  {
    private int number;

    public NewClass(int number)
      {
          setNumber(number);
      }

    public int getNumber()
      {
        return number;
      }

    public void setNumber(int number)
      {
        this.number = number;
      }
  }
```

During creating an object of Newclass1 i am giving value 3, as my knowledge that should be set at the private variable numberNewClass1 of Newclass1 cause i have called the setNumberNewClass1 within the NewClass1 Constructor.

Then i have created another object "call" globally of "NewClass" by giving getNumberNewClass1() method as constructor parameter of NewClass.

Now my problem is when i am calling the the getNumber() method of NewClass by call object within the PrintNumber() method in NewClass1, then it is returning 0. But if i create the object within 
PrintNumber() method, then it is returning the value that was sent. The PrintNumber() method has called in class Encap.

Now my question is if the object crated Globally then the private variable of NewClass is not being  initialized but if it is created locally then the private variable is getting value, why?

Comment: I don't know what you think 'globally' means in Java, but it doesn't mean anything. Your  code would be a lot easier to understand if you used more distinct class names.

Comment: First of all, it's important to understand what you are referring to by "global".  Do you mean using the modifier public or making static objects/variables? Your question is not very clear

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the order of initialization; first the `numberNewClass1` field is initialized with `0` and then `call` is constructed (with that `0`) – Here

```
private int numberNewClass1;
NewClass call = new NewClass(getNumberNewClass1()); //<-- currently 0.
```

You could move the *initialization* of `call` into the constructor of `NewClass1` which will resolve your issue. Something like,

```
private int numberNewClass1;
private NewClass call;

public NewClass1(int number)
  {
      setNumberNewClass1(number);
      call = new NewClass(number); //<-- now it is safe to call
                                   //    getNumberNewClass1(), but
                                   //    we know it is "number". 
  }
```

Comment: is there any problem if we use the getNumberClass1() , call = new NewClass(getNumberClass1());

Comment: It should be okay (but a bit *pointless*) ***as-long-as*** you call `setNumberClass1` *first*.

Comment: does it lose the encapsulation? Actually this structure i am going to use in my next project.

Comment: It isn't a violation of *encapsulation* for a class to modify (or access) its' own fields.

Answer (score 0):

the instance-variable `call` in `NewClass1` is initialized before the constructor has been executed, therefore the value which you pass in your `main` method never reaches `call` within `NewClass1`